# PorterDuffXfermode DST_IN ignoring alpha

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I'm trying to make an implementation similar to using a `BitmapShader` (drawing a bitmap on top of another bitmap with an alpha mask) by using `PorterDuffXfermode`. The code I've been using is along the lines of:

```
drawBitmapWithMaskFromAlpha(Canvas dstCanvas, Bitmap srcBitmap, Bitmap mask) {
    // Draw the fully opaque source in the canvas
    dstCanvas.drawBitmap(srcBitmap, 0, 0, null);

    // Draw the mask with xfermode on top, updating the destination
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    dstCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

The mask is an ARG_8888 bitmap with bits that have a variable alpha and a fixed white color (e.g. 0x23ffffff, 0xa3ffffff) and all the processing is done on in-memory bitmaps, not on-screen (it's inside a Fresco `PostProcessor`). At the end, I would like to have `srcBitmap` drawn in the `dstCanvas` with its alpha updated based on the alpha values in the mask.

The code above seems to be working fine on the latest versions of Android, but on SDK 16 it seems to be ignoring the alpha value completely. When printing the values of pixels it seems that the color part gets updated, while the alpha remains as 0xFF). Any thoughts re. what this may be caused by?

Comment: If we're going with the assumption that `srcBitmap` is opaque, would that make a difference? Isn't the first line actually overriding whatever was there?